# Thymeleaf Java : How to send an input field from the html page to the controller's request parameter

Tags: java, controller, thymeleaf, http-request-parameters

I want update the account.client for a given account.
But i have an error when i submit the "account_update.html" form.

In fact, in the "account_update.html", the user have to update the client for the given account using the "account.client.clientMail" field.

Once teh user submits the "account_update.html" form, the program should send the "account.id" and the new "account.client.clientMail" from the form to the requestParameter of the conroller method "updateAccount"(@PostMapping("/account/updateAccount")). And then the controller "updateAccount" read the corresponding new client(using the accountMail) and then update the account's client.

But i have the error below, looks like the requestParameters are null

21455 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - POST "/account/updateAccount?accountId=null&accountMail=null", parameters={masked}

**Account.java**

```
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String accountId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="client_mail")
    @NotNull
    Client client;
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
    @Id
    String clientMail;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "client",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    List<Account> accounts;
}
```

**AccountController.java**

```
    @PostMapping("/account/updateAccount")
    public String updateAccount(
            @RequestParam(name = "accountId") String accountId, @RequestParam(name = "accountMail") String accountMail) {

        Client client = clientService.getClientByClientMail(accountMail);
        if(client == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No client for this mail");
        }
        Account account= accountService.getAccountByAccountId(accountId);
        account.setClient(client);
        accountService.saveAccount(account);
        return "redirect:/account";

    }
```

**account_update.html**

```
    <form th:action="@{'/account/updateAccount' + '?accountId=' + ${accountIdCurrent} + '&accountMail=' + ${accountMailNew}}"
          th:object="${account}"
          method="POST">

        <label> Account ID </label>
        <input type="text" th:name="accountIdCurrent" th:field="*{accountId}"
               placeholder="Account Mail" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"
               th:readonly="true"
        >

        <label> Client </label>
        <input type="text" th:name="accountMailNew" th:field="*{client.clientMail}"
               placeholder="Account Mail" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Update Account</button>
    </form>
```

```
21455 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - POST "/account/updateAccount?accountId=null&accountMail=null", parameters={masked}
21456 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.paymybuddy.moneytransfert.controller.AccountController#updateAccount(String, String)
21456 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
21468 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
21469 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 5, length 4
21470 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 5, length 4] with root cause
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 5, length 4
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at com.paymybuddy.moneytransfert.controller.AccountController.updateAccount(AccountController.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: The request parameters are null because Thymeleaf only runs on the server when it creates the HTML used in `account_update.html`. So at the time the page is created, `${accountIdCurrent}` is null.

Comment: In addition, this is not how forms work. If you declare the submission action to be `POST` then the input field data will automatically be submitted in the _body_ of the response, using the `name` attribute and the value entered into the field. So you don't even need those query parameters. And if you declared the submission action as a `GET` action, then the same data would be automatically added as query parameter data in the response URL.